# Create Custom Alert Action on Spkunk

Tags: api, splunk

I want to create custom alert action on Splunk that will ingest saved searches from splunk to my software. I have gone through the documentation:
https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/AdvancedDev/ModAlertsIntro

My issue is I want some guidelines in creating this custom alert action. I have gone through a youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqJAc7rpFmQ .He created the UI using code. Do I need to code as well? If yes, do I create folders on my local desktop and then how to integrate the code on splunk for testing? And which folder will pass the saved search to my source code?
Or can I use add-on builder to create this?

So far, I have created an add-on using an add-on builder and declared input parameters and edited the script but it doesnot seem to work.
[image]

I just need some guidance to kick start my project.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "it doesnot seem to work" isn't especially actionable. What error(s) are you receiving? Is this Splunk Cloud or Enterprise/Core?

Comment: I was able to solve this issue. Basically, I created the folder of my app on splunk Enterprise server. And then I created the script files inside this folder and followed the splunk app documentation for the file hierarchy. After the app was created, I packaged it into .spl. And it was done.